# Website Login Bat Script Not Running via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

Full disclosure - scripting isn't my forte. I have the following script that will log into a website for me at 8:00 AM every morning and I use the SENDKEYS command to tab through a few prompts and it ultimately logs me into a remote sever- once I'm logged in I get an email that's sent to me from the website.  Here's a copy of the code:

My Issue:
I can execute this manually and it will run no problem. Using Windows Task Scheduler states that it has successfully ran - but I have no email and no access to the remote server indicating that it did not run as desired.

Can anyone help me here? I've researched this extensively, no luck.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
START CHROME "http website"
timeout /t 10
rem %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
timeout /t 3
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
timeout /t 3
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T
goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

[Task Scheduler General Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIdYG.png)

[Task Scheduler Actions Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC5Ok.png)

[Task Scheduler Conditions Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X7xO.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run the task under your user context?

Comment: How does it log you into a website when you aren't logged in to the computer, and when running under the context of the user `SYSTEM`?

Comment: Hey All, first - thank you for taking the time to respond to this. As stated - you could classify me as a noob when it comes to this. I've tried running this as the SYSTEM user and no success.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that SendKeys do not get executed if you are logged off from the computer. Unfortunately, looks like there is no workaround for this.